# Category Url's ended with numbers like car.html -> car-1.html

Tags: magento-1.8, category, url-rewrite

We have multiple stores in our magento website, few of the category Url's are ended with car-1.html and car-2.html.

```
From basic observation

   Admin category config - car.html
   store one - car-1.html
   store two - car-2.html
   store two - car-3.html

From Url rewrite

   Target Path --------- Request Path 
   products/car.html --- catalog/category/view/id/1884 
   products/car-1.html --- catalog/category/view/id/1884 
   products/car-2.html --- catalog/category/view/id/1884
```

Can any one please tell me, Why the category url's are ended with strange numbers.